# http requests with username and password in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl, controller

from my RoR controller, I'm trying to send http requests that need a username and password.

I tried this

```
url = 'http://192.168.122.198 ...'
uri = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request['Accept'] = 'application/json'
request.body = {'credentials' => {'username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin'}}
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Error 401 Unauthorized
```

Any idea how can I pass the username and password in my request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
uri = URI.parse("http://192.168.122.198")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("admin", "admin")
response = http.request(request)
```